# UTC timestamps for NHibernate Envers revision info

Tags: c#, nhibernate, audit-logging, nhibernate-envers

I'm using NHibernate Envers 1.6.0 and need to use UTC timestamps instead of local for the REVTSTMP column in REVINFO.

I know the bug has been reported ([NHE-122](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NHE-122)) and fixed for future version 2.0

Is there any way I can change the DefaultRevisionInfoGenerator to my own custom IRevisionInfoGenerator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple workaround is to use your own IRevisionListener. There you set the timestamp value to DateTime.UtcNow or whatever.

Assuming you're using FluentConfiguration...

```
var enversCfg = new FluentConfiguration();
enversCfg.SetRevisionEntity<DefaultRevisionEntity>(r => r.Id, r=> r.RevisionDate, yourRevisionListener>();
```

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention...
If you're using your own custom RevisionEntity (which you do above even if it is the "DefaultRevisionEntity"), you need to map this entity.